# Read binary image in julia

Tags: image-processing, julia

How to read binary image file in julia?
`imread(file)` gives following error:

```
ERROR: type: Gray: in T, expected T<:Union(FixedPoint,FloatingPoint), got Type{Bool}
in imread at C:\Users\Harsh\.julia\v0.3\Images\src\io.jl:259
in imread at C:\Users\Harsh\.julia\v0.3\Images\src\io.jl:113
```

Output of versioinfo(true):

```
julia> versioninfo(true)
Julia Version 0.3.0
Commit 7681878 (2014-08-20 20:43 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
           Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
  uname: MINGW32_NT-6.2 1.0.12(0.46/3/2) 2012-07-05 14:56 i686 unknown
Memory: 7.948513031005859 GB (4763.9375 MB free)
Uptime: 111087.5328943 sec
Load Avg:  0.0  0.0  0.0
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz:
       speed         user       nice        sys       idle        irq ticks
#1  2195 MHz   13078796          0    2444890   22142265     348375 ticks
#2  2195 MHz   10343718          0    1964375   25357578     165765 ticks
#3  2195 MHz   15137796          0    1628015   20899875      89390 ticks
#4  2195 MHz   15702750          0    1140187   20822718      73968 ticks
#5  2195 MHz   12287718          0    1952390   23425562      52781 ticks
#6  2195 MHz    9467671          0    1546562   26651421      49406 ticks
#7  2195 MHz   13431750          0    1668484   22565437      36375 ticks
#8  2195 MHz   12820796          0    1473484   23371359      30500 ticks

  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
Environment:
  ANT_HOME = C:\PROGRA~1\APACHE~1.2
  CUDA_BIN_PATH = C:\CUDA\bin64
  CUDA_INC_PATH = C:\CUDA\include
  CUDA_LIB_PATH = C:\CUDA\lib64
  HOMEDRIVE = C:
  HOMEPATH = \Users\Harsh
  JAVA_HOME = C:\Progra~1\Java\jre6
  PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.RB;.RBW

Package Directory: C:\Users\Harsh\.julia\v0.3
3 required packages:
 - DataFrames                    0.5.7
 - DecisionTree                  0.3.4
 - Images                        0.4.10
14 additional packages:
 - ArrayViews                    0.4.6
 - BinDeps                       0.3.5
 - Color                         0.3.8
 - DataArrays                    0.2.1
 - FixedPointNumbers             0.0.4
 - GZip                          0.2.13
 - Reexport                      0.0.1
 - SHA                           0.0.3
 - SIUnits                       0.0.2
 - SortingAlgorithms             0.0.1
 - StatsBase                     0.6.5
 - TexExtensions                 0.0.2
 - URIParser                     0.0.2
 - Zlib                          0.1.7
```

file is this binary file:

[Image Link](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105046436/1.Bmp)

Original RGB image is this, (which has been processed to obtain the above file) This does not give error.:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the output of ``versioninfo(true)`` and what the contents of the ``file`` variable is?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug, thanks for reporting it. It should be fixed if you do a `Pkg.update()`.